# Instaling Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I cannot run Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo S206, it keep asking me to have a Cd recorder to install and copy Ubuntu. What Im doing wrong.
Please help.

Comment: "I cannot run Ubuntu 12.10" - What are you trying to do?, Install Ubuntu on Windows?, boot the LiveCD?, I can hardly understand your issue, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu 12.10, you either have to burn it to a CD or use a USB-stick to install it.

If I assume rightly, you don't want to burn a CD. You should prepare a USB media to install Ubuntu 12.10 hence.

Here is a How-To from Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows